# Mapping over HList with subclasses of a generic trait

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to map a poly1 function over a shapeless HList. Its elements are subclasses of a parameterised trait. However, I get the error "couldn't find implicit value for the Mapper". Here's a basic example:

```
import shapeless._

trait Drink[+A]{
  def v: A
}

case class Water(v: Int) extends Drink[Int]
case class Juice(v: BigDecimal) extends Drink[BigDecimal]
case class Squash(v: BigDecimal) extends Drink[BigDecimal]


object pour extends Poly1{
  implicit def caseInt: Case.Aux[Drink[Int], Int] =
    at(o => o.v)
  implicit def caseDec: Case.Aux[Drink[BigDecimal], BigDecimal] =
    at(o => o.v)
}

object Proc {

  type I = Water ::Squash ::Juice :: HNil
  type Req = Int ::BigDecimal ::BigDecimal :: HNil

  val drinks: I = Water(10)::Squash(15.0):: Juice(1.0)::HNil

  def make()(implicit m: ops.hlist.Mapper.Aux[pour.type, I, Req]): Req  = { drinks.map(pour)}

}
```

Running this code produces 
`Error:(21, 27) could not find implicit value for parameter m: shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper.Aux[pour.type,Proc.I,Proc.Req]`

Although this appears like a simple problem, I haven't found (or recognised) a solution in other answers. My current workaround is to define a case, in `poly`, for each subclass of `Drink`. This is obviously not appropriate with many subclasses of the trait. 
Could there be a better solution (perhaps with TypeTags)?

**UPDATE**

A general answer to this question, for any (reasonable) `Poly1` function, is given by @Jasper_M. (The question is further generalised in [Using shapeless HLists with invariant containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48152668/using-shapeless-hlists-with-invariant-containers).) For the specific transformation `I => Req`  in the above example a simpler solution is

```
import syntax.std.tuple._
import poly._

def makeTwo(): Req =  (drinks.tupled flatMap identity).productElements
```

which gives `10 :: 15.0 :: 1.0 :: HNil`. (Note that `productElements` is wrongly flagged as error in Intellij 2017.2.6. Moreover, the "untupled" version `drinks flatMap identity` causes an "implicit not found" error.)

Comment: The code you've provided does compile on both 2.12 and 2.11.

Comment: @thesamet You are right. A call to `Proc.make()` is missing to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Actually `make` is not generic so `implicit m` is pretty redundant, but that's beside the point here.

Comment: @Jasper-M Thanks for the answer! Would something similar work if each element, in addition, is inside another container? Eg, there's case class Box[+E](elem: E) and I = Box[Water]:: ...; Req = Box[Int] ... ;  drinks = Box[Water(10)] ...       (If necessary, I can edit the question or ask another one.)

Comment: I would say: try it and let me know :-p But I think it should work.

Comment: Yep, just wrapping Box[Drink[Int]] etc works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using polymorphic methods:

```
object pour extends Poly1{
  implicit def caseInt[A <: Drink[Int]] =
    at[A](o => o.v)
  implicit def caseDec[A <: Drink[BigDecimal]] =
    at[A](o => o.v)
}
```